# remove substring starting from one character upto another character

Tags: php, string, replace

How do I remove a part of string starting from '+' and ending at '@' using PHP.

Actually I need some code to replace all of these

```
bob+fake1@gmail.com
bob+anything@gmail.com
bob+something@gmail.com
```

to

```
bob@gmail.com
```

Comment: _"I need some code to replace all of these"_. Suggestion: start by learning regular expressions. Then try to solve the problem, come back with the code and we'll try to help. That's how this works. No code shop I'm afraid.

Comment: You wouldn't be looking to do this to bypass peoples methods of spam filtering would you?

Comment: Actually I tried to solve the problem.. I was using a combination of strpos and str_replace but i thought there may be some better function avaiable.

Comment: @Khan: It's better if you post the code even if it doesn't work, that way we can find a fix. A would still suggest regex though. ie. `/\+.+@/`.

Comment: @elclanrs: I'll be doing so next time specially as I've lost some points :P... Regex are too difficult for me to understand. So I am usign wwaren solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$email = "bob+fake1@gmail.com";
$exploded = explode("@", $email);
$partBeforeAtSign = $exploded[0];
$exploded2 = explode("+", $partBeforeAtSign);
$partBeforePlusSign = $exploded2[0];
```

Untested, but should work I suppose!

Answer (score 0):

```
$email="bob+fake@gmail.com";
$len=strlen($email);
$index=strpos('+');
$index1=strpos('@');
$email_new=substr($email,0,$index-1);
$email_new .= substr($email,$index+1,$len);
```

$email_new is your new string